# Поиск элементов на странице не имеющих «class» и «id», но содержащих текст С# , Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Имеется 5 элементов  на вебстранице содержащих разный текст: 1,7,13,25,4.
Пример: 13

Как Я могу найти только  содержащий "13", объявить его и далее продолжить работать только с ним?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте xPath с поиском по текстовому полю:

**Строго "13"** будет выглядеть так:

```
//*[text()="13"]
```

**Любая строка содержащая "13"** (частичное совпадение) так:

```
//*[text()[contains(.,"13")]]
```

Что написано в этих xPath:

`*` - выберет все теги (элементы) в xml (html) разметке

`[text()="13"]` - из выбранных элементов будет искать те, у которых текстовое поле равно строго "13"

`[text()[contains(.,"13")]]` - сначала выберет все элементы с текстовым полем, то есть сначала применит функцию `text()`, а потом из всех элементов с текстовым полем будет искать те, в которых содержится строка "13" `[contains(.,"13")]`. Точка `.` в `(.,"13")` означает, что в элементах будут "смотреться" все текстовые элементы (их может быть несколько на один элемент (тег)).

**UPD**
Согласно коду из скриншота, div под номером 1 можно идентифицировать вот так:

```
//div[@style="overflow: visible;" and .//*[text()="209"]]
```

Здесь `@style="overflow: visible;"` используется для того, что-бы явно указать на один из трёх div'ов, а не выбирать все div'ы дочерним элементом которых будет текст "209".

Потом логический оператор `and`.

И в конце условие, что тот `div` у которого `@style="overflow: visible;"` должен иметь где-то там внизу элемент с текстом "209"

**UDP2**
На счёт подстановки значения в строку.
***Я пишу на Python 3, поэтому синтаксис в примерах будет отличаться от вашего в C#.***

Есть 2 варианта:

1. Конкатенация строк. Вы формируете строку xPath адреса из трёх частей.

```
one = '//div[@style="overflow: visible;" and .//*[text()="'
two = 209
three = '"]]'
xpath = one + str(two) + three
```

Вы меняете только вторую часть строки и складываете три строки:

Причём `str(two)` - это приведение типа *int* (целого числа `11`) в тип `str` (строки вида `"11"`). В C# приведение в строку по моему делается с помощью `.ToString()`.

2. Это использование функции для редактирования строк. В Python 3 такой функцией является `.format()`, погуглите подобную функицю для C#. Логика такой функции заключается в том, что вы в готовой строке специальным символом фигурных скобок `{}` отмечаете место вставки нужного вам значения.

```
xpath = '//div[@style="overflow: visible;" and .//*[text()="{}"]]'
xpath.format(11)
```

**UPD3**

Что-бы к адресу `//div[@style='overflow: visible;' and .//span[text()='209' ]]` добавить уточнение самого `span` вам нужно не просто вставить `and с новым требованием`, а вставить их в нужное место. И давай-те разберёмся куда))
По смыслу xPath - `//div[@style='overflow: visible;' and .//span[text()='209' ]]` можно разделить на три части:

1-я часть та, которая указывает на то, какой элемент нам нужно найти - `//div`. Мы ищем `div` элемент. Но мы же ищем не все `div` элементы а конкретный, поэтому добавим к `div'у` условие, по которому мы его будем искать - `//div[]`. Добавились квадратные скобки, которые значат, что мы хотим искать `div` по условию внутри этих скобок.

Итог 1-й части - `//div[]`

2-я часть. Мы знаем что одно из условий это - `@style="overflow: visible;"`, но сейчас назовём его `условие1`. И тогда, так будет выглядеть код - `//div[условие1]`. Но мы же выяснили, что нам так же требуется и ещё одно условие - `.//span[text()="209"]` - назовём `условие2`. И кончено же мы знаем что оператор `and` соединяет наши условия. Получается так - `//div[условие1 and условие2]`. Но, во втором условии тоже есть скобки квадратные что с ними то? А это как раз 3-я часть)

Итог 2-й части - `//div[условие1 and условие2]`

3-я часть.
Во втором условии есть квадратные скобки, в котором и находится условие относительно текстового поля у элемента span. То есть, если нам нужны условия относительно span элемента, то нам нужны именно эти скобки. То есть на самом деле, условие с `.//span[text()="209"]` выглядит не как `условие2`, а как `условие2[условие3]`. То есть наш конечный xPath выглядит так - `//div[условие1 and условие2[условие3]]`. И тут наконец наступает кульминация, и мы с вами начинаем понимать, в какие скобки нам нужно вставить дополнительное условие к элементу `span` - `//div[условие1 and условие2[условие3 and условие4]]`.

И конечно же, наш итоговый xPath будет выглядеть так:

```
//div[@style='overflow: visible;' and .//span[text()='209' and @class='cool']]
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 
Если вы знаете как это сделать или как правильно загуглить , подскажите пожалуйста.
На странице о которой идет речь в этом вопросе несколько (div-div-div-span(text)) , div'ы которые идут самыми первыми   помимо других div и нужного текста содержат кнопку "продолжить" (я могу ее выделить используя Classname). , но программа кликает по первой кнопке на сайте. Как можно связать эти действия? Что бы программа сначала находила нужный текст (который под span) и далее искала нужную кнопку непосредственно в главном div'е , который содержит нужный текст, а не кликала по первой?

Comment: @George Если можно, приведите кусок html кода для примера. Если пример вы привести не можете, то есть как минимум два варианта решения проблемы: 1. порядковый номер элемента - div[1], div[2], div[...]. То есть, если кнопка находится на 3-й Диве, то кликайте по div[3] 2. использовать following-sibling или другие оси для поиска относительно "боковых" или других элементов.

Comment: А как Я могу присвоить div порядковый номер?
У меня есть 5 div на странице с составным класснеймом (класснейм до пробела у всех пяти одинаков). Нужный текст находится в третьем div  (div-div-div-span(текст)).

Comment: @George порядковый номер вы пишете в xPath по которому ищите элемент. И кстати, если целевой элемент имеет уникальную часть в `class` или ещё где, почему бы к примеру не использовать `contains` на `class` и искать частичное совпадение с классом? Если можете, хотя-бы скриншотом html код покажите.

Comment: вот скриншот https://pasteboard.co/I7wNCGW.png Цифрами отмечены эти самые div , которых на странице несколько , в развёрнутом первом div красным подчёркнуто число. Нужно идентифицировать div в котором найдется это число , что бы далее Я мог работать внутри него , например искать и нажимать на нужные элементы.

Comment: @George обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо , получилось :) Только заменил даблквоты на одиночные.
А как можно перечислить необходимый текст ? Допустим у меня есть 209 , 13 , 5 для поиска.

Comment: @George обычно я использую одинарные кавычки в коде для выделения строк, а двойные внутри таких строк, а вы видимо наоборот)))) На счёт подставки значений сейчас дополню ответ

Comment: А можно ли в этой строке конкретизировать класс для span в котором есть текст? Дописать ему класс? Что бы в диве искался span , который подходит под класс и текст. Проверял синтаксис xpath , но не нашел как это дописать.
//div[@style="overflow: visible;" and .//span[text()="209"]]

Comment: @George так как вы написали и будет. `//div[@style="overflow: visible;" and .//span[text()="209"]]`, если не работает: а) вы допустили ошибку в написании; б) браузер, через который вы работаете не может обработать такой xPath (что маловероятно) и в Chrome и Firefox такой xPath работает. Так что, ищите в чём проблема

Comment: Я видимо не достаточно чётко объяснил что имею ввиду , в этой строке в диве ведется поиск спэна с текстом 209 , а как в этом диве искать спэн с текстом 209 и одновременно класснеймом "cool"? Что бы не учитывались спэны где просто есть текст 209 , но они другого класса. Если так можно вообще.

Comment: @George в этом xPath уже есть пример, как искать по атрибуту - `@style="overflow: visible;"` означает что вы ищите что-то с атрибутом `style` равным `overflow: visible;`. И тут же есть пример как соединять несколько требований оператором `and`. Это всё что вам нужно, что-бы добавить к `text()="209"` ещё одно требование. Пробуйте.

Comment: у меня получился вот такой код , но он всё равно срабатывает на Span содержащий текст , но не содержащий класс.

(By.XPath("//div[@style='overflow: visible;' and .//span[@class='cool'] and .//span[text()='209' ]]"));   Здесь как я понял код находит и класс и текст в диве и срабатывает, но не проверяет имеет ли один span одновременно нужные и текст и класс. Что нужно поменять ?

Comment: @George вам ещё многому нужно научиться))) я обновлю ответ)